# NDSolve for system of PDEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I am trying to use NDSolve to find the numerical solution to a system of 4 first order PDEs with 8 boundary conditions (I think they are Dirichlet type conditions). There are 4 dependant variables and 2 independant variables. I am using cylindrical coordinates (Rr, Ttheta, Zz) but Ttheta is not used at all and so is excluded (may be the cuase of the problems?). I cannot for the life of me get Mathematica to run the code, I must be doing something wrong but I can't seem to figure out what. If anyone is able to help in anyway, that would be much appreciated.

The error that this code creates changes quite often depending on little 'fixes' I have attempted to make, however I have been slowly learning that a lot of the error messages often don't point to the cause of the problem so I have left them out of this post. The relevant equations in the code are also in the tradition form bellow the code just for ease of reading.

```
(*Constants*)
mi = 1.67*10^-27;
Vn = 10^4 ;
T = 5;
K = 8.617*10^-5;
Z = 1;

EQ0 = Vr[Rr, Zz]*mi*D[Log[ni[Rr, Zz]], Rr] + 
   Vz[Rr, Zz]*mi*D[Log[ni[Rr, Zz]], Zz] + mi*D[Vr[Rr, Zz], Rr] + 
   Vr[Rr, Zz]*mi + mi*D[Vz[Rr, Zz], Zz] == 0

EQ1 = -Vt[Rr, Zz]^2 == -Rr*((Z*K)/mi)*(D[T, Rr] + T*D[Log[ni[Rr, Zz]], Rr]) - 
   Rr*Vn*Vr[Rr, Zz]

EQ2 = Vr[Rr, Zz]*D[Vt[Rr, Zz], Rr]*Rr + Vr[Rr, Zz]*Vt[Rr, Zz] == -Vn*Vt[Rr, Zz]*Rr

EQ3 = Vr[Rr, Zz]*D[Vz[Rr, Zz], Rr] + Vz[Rr, Zz]*D[Vz[Rr, Zz], Zz] == 
    -((Z*K)/mi)*(D[T, Zz] + T*D[Log[ni[Rr, Zz]], Zz]) - Vn*Vz[Rr, Zz]

sol = NDSolve[{EQ0, EQ1, EQ2, EQ3,
    Vz[Rr, 0] == 10^3,
    Vt[Rr, 0] == 10^5*Rr,
    Vr[Rr, 0] == 0,
    Log[ni[Rr, 0]] == -(Rr^2/0.028^2) + Log[8.5*10^8],
    Vz[0.028, Zz] == 0,
    Vt[0, Zz] == 0,
    Vr[0, Zz] == 0,
    Log[ni[0.028, Zz]] == 0},
    {Vz, Vt, Vr, ni},
    {Rr, 0, 0.028}, {Zz, 0, 0.6}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

[image]
Thanks!

Comment: The code contains derivatives of `T`, which is a constant.  Is that intentional?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: @bbgodfrey yeah sorry I should have explained, that is intentional as T can be a function, however at the moment this is simplified a bit for the purposes of getting some sort of result and understanding how to properly use NDSolve.

Comment: `NDSolve` appears to want to solve the PDE system as an initial value problem, which it is not.  It would be nice to solve it using FEM, but `NDSolve` definitely cannot do so for nonlinear equations.  Bottom line, I am not sure that `NDSolve` can handle this problem.  (@MichaelE2, do you have an opinion on this?)

Comment: Warning and error messages are: NDSolve::pdord, NDSolve::ibcinc, NDSolve::bcart, NDSolve::icfail.  `NDSolve` finally returns `{ }`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey hhmmm ok, this problem was given to me as a sort of practice for a question with even more variables and PDEs in the system. It could be possible my mentor rushed a bit when deciding what to make constant, what to exclude etc, so you could be right, this may not be something NDSolve can handle, it might not make enough sense in the first place. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, even if FEM could handle non-linear PDEs, the FEM would not be a good fit here since this is a convection dominated PDE and one most likely would have to use some sort of stabilization technique.